# Refresh angular material table without reload after crud operation

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, angular-material, entity-framework-core

**hi there i'm using angular(v.9) and i'm using asp .net core web api and ef core(v 3.1)
for doing crud operations**

i have region component form which i used as dialog here
[image: region form]

the html code for the form is ***regiondetails.html***

```
<form [formGroup]="service.form"  (submit)="onsubmit()" min-width="200px">

    <mat-toolbar color="primary" width="auto">
            <span>Region</span>

    <span class="fill-remainings"></span>   
    <span>  <button mat-button matSuffix mat-icon-button arial-label="Clear" tabindex="1" (click)="onclose()"><mat-icon>close</mat-icon></button></span>      
    </mat-toolbar><br>
    <mat-grid-list cols="1" rowHeight="300px" min-width="100px">
        <mat-grid-tile>
            <div class="controles-container">
                <input formControlName="Id" type="hidden">
                <mat-form-field>
                    <input maxlength="6" formControlName="Code"  (keyup)= "service.checkcode()"matInput placeholder="Code*"  tabindex="2" autocomplete="off">
                    <mat-error *ngIf="service.form.controls['Code'].errors?.required">the field should not be empty</mat-error>
                    <mat-error *ngIf="service.form.controls['Code'].errors?.pattern">Enter only Alphabetic characters</mat-error>
                    <mat-error *ngIf="service.form.controls['Code'].errors?.notUnique">Code already exist</mat-error>
                </mat-form-field><br><br>
                <mat-form-field>
                    <input maxlength="50" formControlName="Description" matInput placeholder="Description*" tabindex="3" autocomplete="off" >
                    <mat-error *ngIf="service.form.controls['Description'].errors?.required">the field should not be empty</mat-error>
                    <mat-error *ngIf="service.form.controls['Description'].errors?.pattern">Enter only  Alphabetic characters</mat-error>
                </mat-form-field>

                <h2 class="example-margin">Active</h2>

                    <mat-slide-toggle
                          class="example-margin" [checked]=lstatus color="primary"  tabindex="4" (change)="toggle($event)"
                          formControlName="Active">
                          <label class="labeltoggle">{{Active}}</label>
                    </mat-slide-toggle>

                    <div class="button-row">

             <button mat-raised-button class="btn warning btn-xs" type="submit" tabindex="5"  [disabled]="service.form.invalid" >Save</button>
             |<button mat-raised-button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"
                 (click)="onclear()" tabIndex="6" [disabled]= "clear">Clear</button>
            </div>
             </div>
            </mat-grid-tile>
    </mat-grid-list>


</form>
```

ts file **RegionDetails.ts**

```
onsubmit() {
     debugger
     if (this.service.form.valid) {
       if (this.service.form.get('Id').value) {
          this.service.updateregion(this.service.form.value).subscribe(
           res =>{ this.service.form.reset();
          this.dialogref.close();
        this.notificationService.update('updated Successfully');
           },
           err => {
             console.log(err);
           }
          );

       } else {
         this.service.insertregion(this.service.form.value).subscribe(
           res =>{
             this.service.form.reset();
         this.dialogref.close();
         this.service.initializeForm();
       this.notificationService.success('submitted Successfully');
           },
           err => {
             console.log(err);
           }
         );

       }
     }
   }
```

**insertregion** function in service

```
insertregion(region: Region) {
    console.log(region);
   return this.http.post(this.apiurl,region);
  }
```

my material table looks like this...
[image]

create button function on table

```
oncreate() {
   this.service.form.reset();
   this.service.initializeForm();
  const dialogconfig = new MatDialogConfig();
  dialogconfig.disableClose = false;
  dialogconfig.autoFocus = true;
  dialogconfig.width = '400px';
  this.dialog.open(RegionDetailsComponent, dialogconfig);
    this.router.navigateByUrl("Region")
}
```

i used a button click to refresh the page
the function for button click is

```
buttonClick() {
  this.router.navigateByUrl('Country');
  this.router.onSameUrlNavigation;
  this.router.navigateByUrl('Region')
}
```

when i do insert operation the table did not get refresh automatically,but it get updated in the database,
**it only get refresh after i route to other url's or reload the page....**

**any one give me a solution to refresh the table and page without reload and get inserted data in material table.....thanks in advance**

Comment: Just call the function again from which you're bringing data after successful insert/update.

Comment: i   already did that but still the data didn't get refreshed in the table

Comment: Maybe you need to wait the post to finish before run the function to get the list again  
    this.http.post(this.apiurl,region)
    .subscribe( data => 
    {
     // call the list api again
    });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [afterClosed()](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api) method from Angular Dialog. So you call your API again when the modal close.

When you close the modal, you have to send the new Region values

```js
oncreate() {
  this.dialog
    .open(RegionDetailsComponent, dialogconfig)
    .afterClosed()
      .pipe(
        filter(newValues => !!newValues) // If you have formValues
      ).subscribe(newValues => {
      // YOU HAVE TO REPLACE YOUR TABLE CONTENT WITH newValues
    });
}
```

And in your modal.ts

```js
onsubmit() {
  this.service.updateregion(this.form.value)
    .subscribe(values => this.dialogref.close(values))
}
```

Please note that you can go further.
I have not test this code.